# Export multi variable groupby to Excel

Tags: python, excel, group-by, export

I have a groupby that I created:

`df.groupby(['Column','Current Qtr']).sum()`

But when I get to export it, it just exports the integers variables:

[image]

How could I export everything not just the numbers?
I tried with:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Column','Current Qtr']).sum())`

But nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I just found the way:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Column','Current Qtr']).sum().reset_index()
```